# Duplicate packets when crafted from a VM with host OSX

Tags: linux, macos, wireshark, packet, scapy

I'm getting some strange results when crafting packets from a Linux VM to an OSX host (using VirtualBox 4.3.20).

Basically using the script below to reply to ICMP packets. However when I use Wireshark both in the VM and in OSX I get a different amount of packets and I'm interested in the reason for this. In the VM I get what I expect, ICMP Request and the associated reply, however when I capture the same 'session' in OSX I see the ICMP Request and TWO ICMP replies...!

I'm filtering the legitimate replies from the VM using the following iptable rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p ip -i eth0 -j DROP
```

In terms of VM setup i'm using VirtualBox v4.3.20, using a host only adapter.

Sorry about the code quality I'm been hammering at this for a while and didn't cleanup!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket, sys, commands
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from scapy.all import sniff, send, Ether, IP, conf, Raw, ICMP


conf.verbose = 0

def start_procs(iface, bpf):

    pkt_pipe = Queue()

    pkt_cap_th = Process(target=pkt_cap, args=(iface, bpf, pkt_pipe,))
    pkt_cap_th.start()

    pkt_play_th = Process(target=pkt_play, args=(iface, pkt_pipe,))
    pkt_play_th.start()


def pkt_cap(iface, bpf, pkt_pipe):

    while True:

        try:
            sniff(iface=iface, filter=bpf, prn=lambda pkt:pkt_pipe.put(str(pkt[IP])), count=0, store=0, timeout=None)
        except Exception, error:
            print 'Error in pkt_cap: ' + str(error.message)


def pkt_play(iface, pkt_pipe):


    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
    except socket.error , msg:
        print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]

    count = 1

    while True:

        pkt = pkt_pipe.get()
        pkt = IP(pkt)

        pkt = modpkt(pkt)
        dest_ip = pkt[IP].dst

        print 'pkt_play ****** S: ' + str(count)

        print 'pkt_play - ' + pkt.summary()
        print pkt.show2()

        pkt_hex = str(pkt)

        try:
            #send(pkt, iface=iface, verbose=0)
            s.sendto(pkt_hex, (dest_ip , 0))
        except Exception, e:
            print 'Error sending packet: ' + str(e.message)

        print 'pkt_play ****** E :' + str(count)

        count += 1

def modpkt(pkt):

    ipdst = pkt[IP].dst
    ipsrc = pkt[IP].src

    pkt[IP].src = ipdst
    pkt[IP].dst = ipsrc

    pkt[ICMP].type = 0

    del pkt[IP].chksum
    del pkt[IP].len
    del pkt[ICMP].chksum

    return pkt


def main():

    iface = 'eth0'
    srcmac = commands.getoutput('ifconfig ' + iface + ' | grep HWaddr | awk \'{print $5}\'')
    bpf = '(ether dst ' + srcmac + ') and ip'

    print bpf

    start_procs_th = Process(target=start_procs, args=(iface, bpf))
    start_procs_th.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

TIA!

Comment: It would be useful if you included information about the networking setup in your VM... For instance, are you configured as a NAT or as a bridged interface?

Comment: Added it to the OP. Have you ever seen this before? I know there are some issues with OSX and hypervisors...

Comment: Not this specifically, but I've seen a lot of weirdness involving hypervisors and networking on OS X.